# error: package javax.servlet.annotation does not exist in Visual Studio Code

Tags: servlets

I am writing a java servlet in Visual Studio Code and I get the error: package javax.servlet.annotation does not exist. How can I fix it?

I have added the path of annotations-api.jar in the enviromental variables.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First: try to

(1) Copy annotations api. jar to src/main/webapp/WEB INF/lib

(2) Configure annotations api.jar into pom.xml

Or

WebServlet was added in servlet api version 3.0, so please ensure that you are using an updated version and have added it to the project's classpath.
Check servlet-api-2.5 classes, which should does not include WebServlet.class. It is part of servlet-api-3.x classes